Why is there a difference between SendGrid's Email API and Validation API?
When using Sendgrid Email API, any email with an accent doesn't work. After contacting their helpdesk, they confirmed with me that unicode addresses are not supported.
But when I use their validation API an email is considered valid. So unfortunately I cannot rely on that.
How could I check that an email address will work when using the Sendgrid Email API?"
I tried with non-Ascii emails and there is a different behaviour on both

For the "why" this is different, the best address to refer to is probably the sendgrid support ...
